# Passing data from child module to parent module Angular

Tags: nested, angular6, config

```
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { LibChildComponent } from './lib-child.component';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
import { LibParentModule } from 'lib-parent';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LibParentModule.forRoot(CONFIG)
  ],
  declarations: [LibChildComponent],
  exports: [LibChildComponent]
})
export class LibChildModule {
  static forRoot(configs: any): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: LibChildModule,
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: 'LIB_CONFIG',
                    useValue: configValues,
                }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

I want to pass the config data from child module to parent module. when data set to child's forRoot method then it should set to parent's forRoot method.
How can i do that? Is there anybody help me it will be more helpful.

Comment: Did you try using service ?

Comment: Yeah, but how can i pass data from service to imported module.?

Comment: Using setter n getter methods in service, reference - https://www.google.com/amp/s/hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/03/angular2-using-data-service-to-communicate-between-components-in-angular2-application/amp/

Comment: I will share sample code in stackblitz soon